# Why does jQuery 1.4.2 compressed have a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always have noticed this, including in versions before as well. About half way through jQuery's compressed version you'll see some regex:

```
[^[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]*['"]|[^[\]'"]+)+\]|\\.|[^
```

The error appears to be at `['"]`

I'm sure it's not really a syntax error, but all my code editors recognize it as one, which makes development a pain if I try to combine JavaScript files. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I bow for people that write regex rules like that.

Comment: Which tool gives you a syntax error? A browser? IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a character entity in a regular expression, as specified by the square brackets.  There are no restrictions on quote characters in them.  All that's going on is buggy syntax highlighting.  Ask the developer of your editor.

Comment: thanks. I'm using Komodo Edit 5.2.4 and Dreavweaver 4, but I just noticed that the error isn't showing up in Komodo. It was an error I introduced. (ei, Dreamweaver sucks)

Answer (score 2):

your code editor sucks, this isnt a syntax error if its inside of a regex literal, which i suspect it is.

the code editor you use probably doesnt support regex literals properly, and that its a string , which would cause the error